# HttpClient VS Jsoup : Http package header look the same but not the response is difference?

Tags: android, http, network-programming, httpclient, jsoup

As following image capture from Wireshark, **the left side is package create from Jsoup by this code.**

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://pantip.com/login/authentication")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .timeout(9000)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .data("member[email]", username, "member[crypted_password]", password, "action", "login", "redirect", "")
            .followRedirects(false)
            .execute();
```

Right hand side is package create from HttpClient by this following code.

```
 List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("member[email]", username));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("member[crypted_password]", password));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "login"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect", ""));

    HttpPost postLogin = new HttpPost("http://pantip.com/login/authentication");

    postLogin.setEntity(new StringEntity("member[email]="+username+"&member[crypted_password]="+password+"&action=login&redirect="));
    postLogin.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    postLogin.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    postLogin.addHeader("User-Agent", "Dalvik/1.4.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.7; Full Android on x86 Emulator Build/GINGERBREAD)");
```

I try to set every header with the same value include user agent. This is package for Login to the website.

**My problem is** the left hand side package create by Jsoup is working but when I use HttpClient, the server response by login incorrect but the request package is the same, Why?

On my android project, I have to use HttpClient. This is my constrain.

[image: Package Compare]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set the content type in the StringEntity object.  Also why are you making BasicNameValuePairs then just using a String?

Comment: Oh it's my mistake about BasicNameValuePairs I modify code many time to make it work. So, I forgot about it.

Thank for your suggest. I will try ASAP.